# A way to promote method variables to instance variables using XCode

Tags: xcode

A simple question, but I can't find the answer on Google:D Is there a automated way to promote a method variable to a instance variable in XCode? Maybe add it as a @property too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of. Xcode needs to improve its refactoring features.

Do consider [filing an enhancement request with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Will do, I searched this for some time, so it makes sense that it is not possible, although I didn't had a look over the new Xcode 4